# What are the chances of each individual combination type?

Tags: poker-dice

Clarification:

> A combination type is a roll of a set of poker dice which are similar to each other. You have, ranking high to low: 5 of a kind, 4 of a kind, Royal Straight, Straight, Full House, Three of a kind, Two Pairs and Single Pair

What are the chances if getting one of those combination types above? ( In percentage probability)

If you think this is more to do with math than Games, please migrate this to Math SE.

Comment: I'd expect that the question has already been asked at least twice on Math SE, and answered comprehensively through both simulation and combinatorial proof. Not going to go down the rabbithole for it though.

Comment: @Thunderforge edit... Problem has been resolved

Comment: Duplicate of [Poker Dice Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104095/poker-dice-probability)

Comment: @aslum Cross site duplicates are okay on the Stack Exchange network. There is a feature request to allow [crossover questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/191265) where a single question can be shared among multiple sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Poker Dice wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_dice) has a table of probabilities:

```
Hand             Exact probability   Percentage  1 in…   Example
Five of a kind      6 / 7776         0.08%       1296    J J J J J
Four of a kind    150 / 7776         1.93%       51.8    10 10 10 10 A
Full house        300 / 7776         3.86%       25.9    K K K 9 9
Straight          240 / 7776         3.09%       32.4    A K Q J 10
Three of a kind  1200 / 7776         15.43%      6.5     9 9 9 K J
Two pair         1800 / 7776         23.15%      4.3     Q Q 9 9 A
One pair         3600 / 7776         46.30%      2.2     10 10 K Q 9
Bust              480 / 7776         6.17%       16.2    A K Q J 9
```

6^5 = 7776 rolls

There are 6 ways to make 5 of a kind = 6 / 7776